# SQLCMD error SQL Native Client is not installed Correctly

Tags: sql, database-backups, sqlcmd

I am trying to backup my sql database. I have added the below command into a batch file. When double clicking the batch file I receive:

sqlcmd: Error: connection Failure. SQL Native Client is not installed correctly. To correct this, Run SQL server setup.

I have already ran the SQL server setup, uninstalled and re-installed the SQL Native Client. I am not sure what my next option is and hoping the community would be abel to point me in the right direction.

```
 "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE" -S .\TAMV9 -q"BACKUP
 DATABASE 'C:\sqlbackup\tambackup.sql'"
```

Comment: I am facing same error!